# Android Launch Icon doesn't work with .png image but works with .jpeg

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons, appicon

I spent several hours trying to upload png image as App Launch Icon with no success. Cleaning, restarting, adding png files manually to folders didn't help.
The problem was fixed only after I changed png to jpeg.

Does anyone know why it happened?

Comment: What exactly is the "problem"? "Doesn't work" is next to useless when debugging.

Comment: After build Android smartphone doesn't see png icon and it only shows standard android icon. The problem disappears with jpeg only.

Answer (score -1):

No detailed info, but you could go to [this link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher) and:

- Click image tab
- insert your image and select all features
- download it
- replace all image formats (xxhdpi, hdpi, ...) in your
  drawable-xxhdpi, drawable xhdpi,... and mipmap-xxhdpi,
  mipmap-xhdpi,... folders.
- set the `android:icon = "@drawable/myicon"` in AndroidManifest.xml

the format of the image(png or jpeg) is irrelated to the issue.